# Wildfly - Java8 - UT010009(does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet)

Tags: spring, servlets, wildfly

Migrating java7 to java8 and used wildfly to deploy the services. During deployment following Error is blocking the migration.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet dispatcher of type class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet

@Jboss-deployment-structure.xml following exclusion is defined

```
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javax.api" />
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" />         
    </exclusions>
```

spring version  "4.3.4.RELEASE"

Any advice  :)
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're ending up with two different `javax.servlet.Servlet` on your class path. You should not be excluding the `javax.api` and `javax.servlet.api` modules and you should make sure your deployment does not contain the a servlet API or implementation module.